# A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree

Tags: flutter

There seem to be many questions regarding this error but I'm yet to find an answer that will work in my situation.

The behaviour I'm seeing is that the Dismissible works, it fires and deletes the item, but for a moment it shows an error in the ListView.  I'm guessing it's waiting for the tree to update based on the Stream<List>, which in turn is removing the record from Firebase.

My StreamBuilder...

```
return StreamBuilder<List<Person>>(
      stream: personBloc.personsByUserId(userId),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

...

}
```

My ListView.builder()

```
ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        var person = snapshot.data[index];

                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context)
                                .pushNamed('/reading/${person.personId}');
                          },
                          child: Dismissible(
                            key: Key(person.personId),
                            direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                            onDismissed: (direction) {
                              personBloc.deletePerson(person.personId);
                            },
                            background: Container(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(
                                      FontAwesomeIcons.trash,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Delete',
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                            child: AppCard(
                              //Bunch of properties get set here
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
```

My deletePerson

```
  deletePerson(String personId) async {
    fetchPersonId(personId).then((value) {
      if (value.imageUrl.isNotEmpty) {
        removeImage();
      }

      db.deletePerson(personId);
    });
  }
```

I've tried changing the onDismissed to a confirmDismiss with no luck.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: i think the problem is with the order of the flow. you are deleting the row from your list but its still exist in the original data and you are not actually deleting it untill your call back get triggered . try to delete the item immidiatlly fron your data that you supplied to the list and wait for the call back if its success ok , if not revert it back , i hope it helps

Comment: I've tried adding `snapshot.data.removeAt(index)` wrapped in a setState() statement, but no change in behaviour.

Comment: I guess it happen on every `Dismissible` widget wrapped in `Stream Builder` it took time before it actually deleted from the database but `Stream Builder` still listen to it until then. Have you try using Future Builder instead?

Comment: I agree with @AldyYuan. It does seem like the `Stream` rebuilds the `ListView` with the item with the specific `ID` because it hasn't yet been deleted, and once it does get deleted, and updates the view, it disappears. But I find it strange that this is happening because if you aren't updating the data that the `Stream` is listening to, there is no reason for the `Stream` to rebuild the `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making a couple of changes to my code to address this.

I added a BehaviourSubject in my bloc to monitor whether the delete was taking place or not. At the beginning of the firestore delete I set this to true and then added a .then to the delete to set it back to false.

I then added a Streambuilder around the ListView on the screen to monitor the value of this  and show a CircularProgressIndicator when true.

It now looks like this:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you dismiss with a `Dismissible` widget but haven't removed the item from the list being used by the `ListView.builder`. If your list was being stored locally, with latency not being an issue, you might never see this issue, but because you are using `Firestore` (I assume, based on your mention of`Firebase`) then there is going to be some latency between asking the item to be removed from the `DB` and the list getting updated on the app. To avoid this issue, you can manage the local list separately from the list coming from the `Stream`. Updating the state as the stream changes, but allowing you to delete items locally from the local list and avoiding these kind of view errors.